# Maping a Linux Drive on Windows 2016

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, windows-server-2016, openldap

I have a Red Hat Linux 8.7 server (87server) with an exported disk (bigdata).
On my Linux network, I can mount the drive with no problems:

```
mount /mnt/bigdata 87server:/bigdata
```

The access to the directory is restricted to the linux group datausers

```
[root@87server /] # ls -ld /bigdata
drwxrwx---   root   datausers     /bigdata
```

Everything works as expected.

But ...

I have users on Windows (Citrix running on Windows 2016). Some of these users need to access bigdata from the windows side.

*Herein lies the rub*, as Shakespeare would say
Red Hat uses LDAPS for authentication. Windows uses AD. All users have accounts on both LDAPS & AD, but the group 'datausers' does not exist in AD.

Mapping the drive works, but does not allow access (as it should, because the windows user is not a member of the group).

When I try to map the drive on Windows and tell it to use username & password, I always get the error that the credentials are invalid:

```
Type the password for \\87server\bigdata: <Enter LDAP Password>
System error 1326 has occurred.

The username or password is incorrect.
```

How can I get Windows to authenticate me to the Red Hat LDAPS server and allow access to the /bigdata directory?

Of note:
I am an Admin on Red Hat only, not on the Windows system. I know the Windows admins, but they are really busy so I want to minimize the number or requests to them.
My system engineers are *vehemently* against using SAMBA, so if that is the only viable answer, I need to have a bit of proof to change their minds.